# shows Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for php

Tags: php, netbeans

```php
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>

        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "Hello, world! This is my first PHP project!";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

While I run a sample code in php using netbeans it shows the error like this

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So what is the problem and what I have to do for this?

Comment: What sample code? You didn't show any.

Comment: Seems its a configuration problem not a PHP problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a number of local assets and managed to solve my problem. For some reason (possibly an issue with my CMS' caching), URLS that should have been based from localhost:8000 were instead being written as localhost:8080. In my Netbeans project properties, I changed the server port to 8080, and everything works as expected.

[image: project preferences]

Before trying this, you might first want to try flushing any caches in the app and (for good measure) your browser's cache.

Comment: thank you. you pointed me in the right directions with the ports